# On the stack of bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

Let $K$ denote the function field $\mathbb C((t))$ and let $X$ be a smooth projective curve of genus $g\geq 2$ over $K$. Let $r\geq 2$ be some positive integer. Let $B$ denote the moduli of vector bundles of rank $r$ with trivial determinant. Is $B$ a very good stack(in the sense of Beilinson and Drinfeld)?

Comment: Are you asking about "very good" in the sense of Beilinson and Drinfeld: roughly that the inertia is "small"?

Comment: @Jason Starr Yes, whether the very good property in the sense of Beilinson and Drinfeld holds over the function field $\mathbb C((t))$?

Comment: You need some inequality on the genus $g$ and the rank $r$.  It is clearly false when $g$ equals $0$ and when $r$ equals $2$.

Comment: @Jason Starr thanks, I assume $g\geq 2$.

Comment: I don't think it depends on the field. I think BD prove that the stack of bundles is very good for all curves of genus $\geq 2$.